# Xamarin - Cannot use iOS Emulators?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Visual Studio 2019

I recently upgraded Xamarin.Forms to version v4.5.0.530.  This required me to upgrade xCode on the Mac to 11.4.  This required me to upgrade the Mac OS to Catalina.  OK I did all of that.  Since then though:

If I run the project on the iPhone connected to the Mac it still **WORKS** fine (as before).

However, if I try and use one of the emulators on the PC (ipad etc) it **FAILS** to deploy with the following message:

```
 Selected device is not a physical device. Please select a valid device before deploying the application.
```

Well obviously it is not a physical device!?!

Of course I am doing everything the same way I did it before the upgrade, choosing Debug, iPhoneSimulator, my iOS project, iPad Pro (9.7... etc)

So, it works on the physical iphone but not on any of the apple emulators (android phone/emulators work fine).

Has anyone any ideas why this might be?

Comment: Can you start an iOS sim via an Xcode-based iOS project?

Comment: I don't really use the Mac, I would have to work out how to do that.

Comment: More Information:  It works in Release mode, but not Debug?!?!

Comment: Just related to Debug Build on emulators.  Release Build works fine on emulators and both work fine on the physical device??

Comment: Does this error appear if you create a new project and run? If so, report a problem through the visual-studio.

Comment: Sorry about slow response.  YES it does work on a default App.  There must be something wrong with my project.  Any ideas what it may be (currently comparing the 2)

Comment: They seem to be exactly the same (at least the iOS project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a setting at Solution level.  For some reason with 'iPhoneSimulator' selected at the top, against the iOS project 'iphone' was selected.  Changed it to 'iPhoneSimulator' and all is good in the world again.

[image]